# Hexadecimal literals in Spring XML configuration

Tags: xml, spring, hex

How can I use hexadecimal literals in Spring XML configuration file?

```
<value>#{T(java.lang.Integer).decode("0xFF")}</value>
```

works, but I am too lazy to write such expressions for every hex literal I need. Are there any shortcuts or syntax sugar?

Comment: You can call static methods in Spring configuration files?  Where did you pick that up?

Comment: Yep! It is [Spring EL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) and I definitely can use it in my configs with #{...} notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of tries I got it. May be helpful to somebody:

The problem was that actually I tried to configure ARGB color values in XML. `0xFFFF0000` is correct value and means `255` alpha and red and `0` green and blue. But it is not valid [integer Literal](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/expression/spel/ast/IntLiteral.html) (kind of a bit magic for me: `0xFFFF0000` is actualy `-65536` when converted to int in Java, but `Integer.parseInt()` fails to parse this string)

So the solution was to create long and cast to int:

```
<value>#{0xFFFF0000L.intValue()}</value>
```